# The connection was refused by the host computer

Tags: vnc, centos-7, vncserver

After installing `tigervnc-server` and it's packages and config `VNC` when I
 want to connect to host with  `VNC Viewer` I got this error:

```
The connection was refused by the host computer
```

This is works that I done in `vmware` centOS 7 :
config `/etc/systemd/system/vncservice@:6.service`
in this file change the `<USER>` to wanted user and save that
and then `sudo systemctl daemon.reload`
then `sudo systemctl enable vncserver@:6.service` 
disable firewall `sudo systemctl disable firewalld.service`
stop firewall `sudo systemctl stop firewalld.service`
after this configs I come back to my `windows` host
and using `VNC Viewer` and enter my server IP by encryption `Let VNC server choose`
 but after a second got this:`The connection was refused by the host computer`

Comment: wish to solve this problem not a little change !@Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007